# Certificate False Alarm in WinRM's Database and Web Site Deployment Tasks of TFS 2015 vNext Release

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have an error "Deployment failed on machine xx.x.xx.11 with following message after configured and executed `WinRM -SQL Server DB Deployment` or `WinRM - IIS Web App Deployment` :

`System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server xx.x.xx.11 failed with the following error message : The server certificate on the destination computer (xx.x.xx.11:5986) has the following errors: The SSL certificate contains a common name (CN) that does not match the hostname."`

I added the certificate name to agent's host file to associate xx.x.xx.11 with it. It still can not be fixed. How can this been fixed? Can the task ignore SSL check?

Comment: Could it be that the certificate used on the destination machine is invalid ?

Comment: Do you use task download from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp? Is your TFS version TFS 2015 Update 2 onwards or VSTS? How about use -allowUntrusted option in WinRM - IIS Web App Deployment?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT, My TFS version is 14.102.25423.0 (Update 3).  Can not find where the -allowUntrusted option is.  I unchecked "Test Certificate" checkbox but the same error still appears.

Comment: @NielZeeman, the certificates have not expired yet and they came from Symantec CA.  The certificate names match the name in the TFS server's host file corresponding to the IPs.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT, I downloaded the task (ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp-1.2.4.vsix) from the link you point to.

Comment: What's the common name of your certificate? Refer to this question for how to check it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103461/get-common-name-cn-from-ssl-certificate. And then you can follow the steps in this article to setup the host file: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30920.vnext-release-management-template-for-on-premise-target-server-in-un-trusted-domain.aspx. Make sure you restarted the build service after the host file is updated.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT, https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/sql-server-database-deployment documents checkbox "Test Certificate" as "If you choose the HTTPS option, set this checkbox to skip validating the authenticity of the machine's certificate by a trusted certification authority."  Why was certification validation not skipped?  A bug or I missed something.

Comment: The "Test Certificate" checkbox does not skip checking the certificate, it only specifies that the server certificate being used is a test certificate, meaning that the certificate wasn't issued by an official authority.  This is true when WinRM configures certificates that are self-signed.

You can view these certificates by opening a management console on the TARGET machine (run mmc from CMD) and adding a certificate snap-in for the computer account (File > Add Snap-in... > Certificates).  They are listed under Personal > Certificates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with the host file or the build agent, but rather the server certificate on the **TARGET** machine.  For me, I was using VSTS to deploy to an **Azure VM** when I encountered the issue, but the solution remains the same for **onsite** machines as well.

For an Azure VM deployment, the issue occurs when you create a VM without a **DNS Name Label** for your public IP, and then later add one (something like `example.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com`).  It can also occur if you change the DNS name label.

---

## Issue

You'll want to check how you're connecting to the machine.  In your case, we want to use `xx.x.xx.11:5986`.  Port **5986** is used by WinRM and/or VSTS for deployments, so we want to include the port number.  For me, VSTS started trying to use `example.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com:5986` since I had recently added a DNS name label.  We'll call this the **target machine address**.

On the **target** machine, open up PowerShell or Command Prompt as an administrator, and enter the command '`winrm e winrm/config/listener`'.  It should return two listeners, one for **HTTP** and another for **HTTPS** (if one is not listed for HTTPS, don't worry we'll add one later).  Pay particular attention to the **Hostname** for the HTTPS listener.  If this doesn't match the **target machine address** we found earlier, that is what is causing the error.  The **CertificateThumbprint** corresponds to a server certificate on the machine.

To view these certificates, from PowerShell or Command Prompt, type `mmc` and press enter.  Go to 'File' > 'Add/Remove Snap-in...'.  Select 'Certificates', and click **Add**.  In the dialog box, select 'Computer Account' and click **Next** then **Finish**.  Under 'Certificates' > 'Personal' > 'Certificates', you will see the certificate being used by the WinRM configuration.  Certificates here that are self-signed are considered **Test Certificates** because they are not backed by an official certificate authority.  We will need to create one that represents the **target machine address** you want to use.

You can also view certificates in IIS under '**Server Certificates**'.

---

## Solution

Make sure you know what address you want to use to connect to the machine.  This is the **target machine address**.

On the **target** machine, open PowerShell as an administrator.  Enter the following command.

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName WhateverTargetMachineAddressYouNeed -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

This creates a new server certificate for your target address with a validity period of one year.

Next, we want to recreate the WinRM listener for HTTPS transport types to use the new certificate.  Open IIS and look at **Server Certificates** for your web server.  You should see the one you just created.  Right-click on it and select 'View...'.  In the **Details** tab, copy the **Thumbprint** for the certificate.  You can also do this from the mmc if you prefer.

Enter the following commands one at a time in PowerShell.

```
winrm delete winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS
```

Then:

```
winrm create winrm/config/listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="WhateverTargetMachineAddressYouNeed";CertificateThumbprint="TheThumbprintYouCopied";port="5686"}'
```

**Done!**  If you enter `winrm e winrm/config/listener` in PowerShell, you should now see the HTTPS transport using your new certificate.

If anything in your release definition or deployment scripts is using the old address (for me, the Azure VM IP address), be sure to update them to use the new **target machine address** (for me, the Azure VM DNS name label) WITH port number.  In VSTS, make sure you check the box for using a '**Test Certificate**'.  Good luck!

For more information, you can go here:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windows-azure/1289/configure-winrm-execute-powershell-remote-azure-with-arm